# Зациклить звук без пробелов

Tags: jquery

Чтобы не делать трек с цикличным звуком на пару минут, решил зациклить тот фрагмент через `.loop`. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой. Между повторами есть секундный пробел. Есть какие-то способы избежать этого и сделать звук непрерывным?

```
var sound = document.getElementById("main_audio");
sound.play();
sound.loop = true;
```

Comment: Говорят, что нет (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520220/6138795). Но кто-то пытается (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22446616/6138795 ,   https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938297/6138795)  и вроде что-то получается

Comment: А если мне одновременно придется запустить например массив из 2-3 звуков с цикличностью, то для каждого нужен свой setTimeout. Я только начинаю изучать jquery, и не знаю как для каждого 'звука' создавать собственный setTimeout.

Comment: https://codepen.io/woodwoerk/details/rxrLqa

Comment: Может есть плагины, которые избавляют от этого зазора? Он появляется при старте воспроизведения, а не завершении...